# issue in react redirecting,how to use history.push

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I'm having difficulty in redirecting a react route to other when I a particular condition is satisfied, I found that solution is useHistory but I cannot/am I'm not able to use that in my class component
how can I go about doing that

```
import React,{useState,useContext,Component} from 'react'
import Navbar from '../../shared/components/navigation/Navbar';
import {AuthContext} from '../../shared/context/auth-context'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default class Auth extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLogin : true,
            name:'',
            email:'',
            password:''
        };
      }
    
    render() {

        const authSubmitHandler = async event=>{
            event.preventDefault();
            // AuthContext.login();
            const data = new FormData(event.target);

            if(this.state.isLogin){
                try{
                    console.log(data)
                   const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/users/login',{
                        method:'POST',
                        headers:{
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        body:JSON.stringify({
                            email: data.get('email'),
                            password: data.get('password')
                          })
                    });
                        const responseData = await response.json();
                        console.log(responseData);
    
                        if(response.ok){
                            return <Redirect to='/' />
                        }
                }
                catch(err){
                    console.log(err);
    
                } 
            }
            else{
            try{
                console.log(data)
               const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup',{
                    method:'POST',
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body:JSON.stringify({
                        name: data.get('name'),
                        email: data.get('email'),
                        password: data.get('password')
                      })
                });
                    const responseData = await response.json();
                    console.log(responseData);

                    if(response.ok){
                        return <Redirect to='/' />
                    }
            }
            catch(err){
                console.log(err);

            } 
        }
    }

        const switchModeHandler = (event)=>{
            this.setState({isLogin:!this.state.isLogin})
            // this.state.isLogin =!this.state.isLogin;
        }


        return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Navbar/>
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={authSubmitHandler}>

                {!this.state.isLogin &&
                <label>
                username
                <input name="name" type="text" id="name" label="your name"/>
                </label>
                }

                email
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" label="email" />

                password
                <input  name="password" type="password" id="password" label="password" />

                <button type="submit">submit</button>
            </form>
            <button onClick={switchModeHandler}>switch to {this.state.isLogin?'SIGNUP':"LOGIN"}</button>
        </div>
        </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

here, this is the part which I want to use to redirect,currently nothing is happening when I press submit on the auth form

```
if(response.ok){
   return <Redirect to='/' />
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of things I'd change in your component, but to answer your specific question, what you want is not `useHistory`. That is a hook that you would be able to use in you weren't writing class components. In your case, what you should be using is `withRouter`, a HoC that gives you the prop `history` that you need.

Remove the export default from the first line, add the following import

`import { withRouter } from "react-router";`

And use the HoC like this:

`export default withRouter(Auth);`

Then, you will be able to access the history prop, with which you can call push and change the route in your method

I'd check react-router's docs for more details https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter